# How to extend Eclipse's Java editor to recognize my own elements

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I want to add references to other elements inside javadoc. The javadoc should look similar to:

```
/**
* ...
* @my.tag SomeElement
*/
```

I want to reuse the existing Java editor inside Eclipse. Of course I can type above javadoc already, however I'd like to add some features:

- Navigation: upon Ctrl-Click / F3 I want to navigate to the editor showing SomeElement
- Auto-completion: Ctrl-Space should complete the text / show valid alternatives
- Checking: I want to create a warning marker and underline the SomeElement if it cannot be found

I already figured out that I can do the auto-completion by using the extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer`, though this seems to be little more complex than I had hoped, so I might be on the wrong track here?

For checking my elements I might be able to use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant`, which can generate markers upon compilation which afaik happens with every save operation.

But how can I can manage the navigation feature? Any pointers are welcome!

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?  The last time I checked, the Java editor was made up of Eclipse internal classes, which meant that the code and method signatures could change from Eclipse release to Eclipse release.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I use Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2), but generally I would prefer to use an API / extension points to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For navigation you can provide a [Hyperlink Detector](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html?cp=2_1_1_197). You'll want to look at how the Java Editor and its existing detectors are declared in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plug-in to determine the correct target ID.

Comment: I have the HyperlinkDetector working now, however this only provides navigation for Ctrl-Click, not for F3. Any ideas how I can solve that?

Comment: Is your detector not being *called* at all, or just not handing the call properly?

Comment: When pressing the Ctrl+Moving the mouse then my detector is called immediately, even before clicking. However pressing F3 (aka "go to definition") does not call it at all, the status text in eclipse says "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor".

Comment: Your detector returns a hyperlink for what's being hovered over or not. Only when a returned hyperlink is activated should it actually open an editor, so are you returning one in the latter case?

Comment: No. My detectHyperlinks() method is not triggered by pressing F3.